# How to stop a request from going out to doGet(e) every time a draft containing embedded link to web app is SENT? (Google Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

Hello stackoverflowers and other great inhabitants of planet Earth, and beyond!

### EDIT:
Same issue is still relevant, but after more trial and error - I found out that ALL of my scripts act the same. The one that seemed to behave differently was just SENDING DRAFTS FASTER than the others, and in doing so it was 'asking' doGet() to handle too many requests at once, hence it was not executing on most occasions. but still, sending the draft triggered a request.

My goal is to embed a url to a doGet() web app (built with GAS) inside an email message - which ONLY WHEN CLICKED will identify the email's recipient, thanks to some unique user-strings included as parameters of said url.

This works like a charm. When the embedded link is clicked inside the email body >> it triggers the web app which takes those parameters does the rest.

Important to note! I have two scripts that do the same thing, follow the same procedure to embed the url in the email body and they both work.

Both use GAS to create a draft with this embedded url, using:

```js
var url_to_webapp = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKf...VJ/exec?to=<email_address>&userID=<userID>&removalCode=<removalCode>' 

var html = some html...
var htmlBody = html + url_to_webapp  // 'url_to_webapp' gets converted by Gmail to a <a href ...>

var draft = GmailApp.createDraft(EmailAddress, emailSubject, msgBody, { 
              from: thisAlias,
              name: name, 
              replyTo: thisAlias,
              htmlBody: htmlBody
              });

var draftID = draft.getId();
```

Parameters are encoded with a "encodeURIComponent(UserID.replace(/'/g, "")" type line.

**However,** when it comes to ONE of the scripts, the web app also gets a request the minute I use:

```js
var draft = GmailApp.getDraft(draftID);
draft.send();
```

Which then triggers the web app logic - unwantedly.

What I DO want to happen is that only when the embedded link is clicked >> the web app gets a request. Not when the draft is sent.

Again, it doesn't happen with the other script, which uses the same code to generate the same format of url (from a different web app on a different project) and send the draft from the same Gmail account.

---

After reading quite a lot I tried:

1. Duplicating the spreadsheet and the scripts attached several times
2. Disabling Streak add on (which also tracks emails sent from gmail).
3. Inspecting the outgoing link. I found that when the draft iscreated,
   even before it's sent, AFTER my embedded url code Gmail adds a
   "...data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKf...&source=gmail&ust=1656656998227000&usg=AOvVaw1p-L0mcxAZU1pyimSRufks"
   to the href, meaning it sends my script to google search?!
4. I confirmed that when pasting the
   "https://www.google.com/url?q=https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKf"
   into the browser address line and pressing enter DOES trigger the
   request and therefor the web app. Anyway, I can't understand why
   this part gets added, how to stop this or if this is the cause. BUT
   MY OTHER SCRIPT DOESN'T GET TRIGGERED when same appended code is
   added to outgoing drafts, at the time of sending.
5. I tried to use the same logic to track email openings, by embedding
   a tracking  tag with less parameters, which also uses a GAS
   webapp with a doGet(e) to find out when people open our emails >>
   and same thing still happens. Meaning the web app gets a request
   when the email is sent, and then once again when the email is
   opened. This gives a clue, because the meaning is that this is an
   intended behavior, at least in some situations.
6. When I generate the draft with the same code, but send it manually
   by clicking "Send" in the draft using Gmail's gui - the webapp
   doesn't get triggered. Only when 'draft.send()' is called, the web
   app gets a request and handles it.

---

So basically, my question boils down to:
How to prevent this unwanted request from reaching my web app, or what could cause ONE of my scripts to result in Gmail drafts that DO NOT trigger the web app when sent (which is the desired behavior).

p.s. first time asking here, thanks to anyone who can help (very impressed with this community, can't wait to help someone!)

Comment: `I have two scripts` What's the difference between those two?

Comment: They both handle replying to leads that contact us. One drafts emails for leads on spreadsheet A, and the other drafts emails for leads on spreadsheet B. Two parallel processes that use the same code to generate the same url format. Both are bound to their respective spreadsheet.

Comment: Not sure if this will work but your can try using the [advanced Gmail service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail) to send the draft instead.

Comment: So, why are there two spreadsheets? Why not move everything from not-working spreadsheet to the working one?

Comment: Can you share more information on how to reproduce it? I have tested and the doGet only gets executed when clicked.

Comment: The purpose of your code snippet is not so clear, but is there any chance that Gmail will check if your link is safe to send?

Comment: @TheMaster Two different flows, two different templates series, two different teams working on each flow.

Comment: @TheAddonDepot Thank you very much - I will check that if I can't figure out how to get the desired behavior from my code (which I can accomplish, on a different project)

Comment: @Kessy - for simplicity, I was following this tutorial at the time: [link](https://medium.com/swlh/tracking-email-opens-with-gmail-sheets-and-apps-script-69f65afc3074),  the code which is embedded in the email body is right after the line that ends with "...the first function we built."

This code returns an <img> tag that is then embedded in the url (where 'imgURL' in that function is the url of the web app I've built).

It works, just gets a request at the time the draft gets sent.

Comment: @leetom the code embedded in the link is shown in this link: [link](https://medium.com/swlh/tracking-email-opens-with-gmail-sheets-and-apps-script-69f65afc3074) - right after the line that ends with "...the first function we built.". It's a simple tracking pixel.

Comment: You might need to create a issue in issuetracker. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for  official documentation, free resources and more details.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the last comment, you can go to [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640) and on the Apps Script component create an issue.

This is the component template for it:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905